# Joomla module development: How to use template and alternative layouts?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-module

In my custom module, my themes are structured like this:

```
/modules/mod_ab_art/tmpl/default/default.php
/modules/mod_ab_art/tmpl/arz/default.php
```

I have an option for the user to select a theme from the admin section like this:

```
<field
    name="theme"
    type="list"
    default="default"
    label="MOD_AB_ART_THEME_LABEL"
    description="MOD_AB_ART_THEME_DESC">
    <option value="default">MOD_AB_ART_THEME_DEFAULT</option>
    <option value="arz">MOD_AB_ART_FIELD_ARZ</option>
</field>
```

I also have an alternative layout option as shown below but this is not displaying anything in the dropdown list. I think this is supposed to display `Default` in the dropdown list. Is it because of the theme subdirectories inside the `tmpl` directory? Does alternative layout work only with a single theme?

```
<field name="altlayout"
    type="modulelayout" 
    label="JFIELD_ALT_LAYOUT_LABEL" 
    description="JFIELD_ALT_MODULE_LAYOUT_DESC" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Although David's answer is 100% correct, I would like to clarify the distinction between template overrides and having multiple layout files packaged with your module.  In the end, they both accomplish the same things.  It just depends on if you want/need the alternate layouts encapsulated within the module entirely or not.

Regardless, you would need to remove the extra directory exactly like David explained above.  So your tmpl directory will have both the default.php and arz.php files in it.

The second thing would be to alter the code in your modules entry point to capture the 'theme' parameter and use it when rendering the layout:

```
require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_ab_art', $params->get('theme', 'default'));
```

You'll notice this is identical to almost all the core modules execution of the same line of code, except it pulls the 'layout' parameter, which is a listing of layout overrides in the active template for the particular module.

Answer (score 2):

Joomla would not expect the folders under `tmpl` for a module. It would expect just the full layout to be one file and each to be named a different name to signify the layout. So you would probably do best to have layout files like this:

```
/modules/mod_ab_art/tmpl/default.php
/modules/mod_ab_art/tmpl/arz.php
```

You can have as many different files in the `tmpl` folder and even different ones in the theme (typically at `templates/*template_name*/html/mod_ab_art/override.php`).